# Designing rich list

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am planning to develop rich list for a test widget . I have designed how it should look

Screenshot:

I don't want to go the conventional putting divs inside the table method. Because I have experienced lot of problems.

Can you give any other suggestions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I've built something similar and would suggest you start out from a list. So for example

```
<ul>
  <li>Your content here</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

You then will need some CSS trickery to make it look ok,

```
ul {
   list-style:none;
   padding:0;
}
```

This is the same approach as to a link-menu. It's a list and should thus be represented as such :)

Comment: this is not what I was looking for

Comment: Guess widget should have warned me. Oh well.